# Учебные материалы по Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

Доброго дня. Уважаемые знатоки Java EE. Подскажите, пожалуйста, учебные материалы по Spring Framework.

Comment: Когда-то помог начать ресурс http://spring-source.ru/

Comment: это тот случай когда лучше читать мануалы. этот фреймворк очень хорошо документирован

Answer (score 2):

Я уже довольно давно собираю коллекцию из ссылок на [статьи по Spring](http://freesource.info/wiki/devel/Java/Spring/links). Надеюсь, что найдёте для себя что-нибудь интересное.